# Is it possible to decode property class from metadata _property_

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When i make a meta query to retrieve entity properties (columns), i retrieve only this:

Kind: **property**
ID: 0
Name: propDate
property_representation = INT64

i have no enough info to map this property to a java.util.Date class because INT64 can be java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Short, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long

In the gae console/datastore viewer, i see that the date is formatted ...
has it been decoded from metadata or from data ?

any idea !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Engine datastore is schemaless. Your metadata queries return information about the properties that are indexed, but know nothing about the actual data in your entities. You can actually have entities of the same Kind that have different types for the same property name, and if these types have the same underlying representation, they'll be indistinguishable in the metadata. You'll notice in the datastore viewer that the columns in the view table (which should *not* be thought of as "columns" in the RDBMS sense) are not labelled with types. This isn't just a UI choice; it's because there inherently is no type for a property name at that level.

The actual datastore types for each property within an entity are stored with the entity in the protocol buffer. These aren't Java (or Python) types, but things like "atom:category", "georss:point", "gd:when", etc. (and, of course, more familiar "int", "float", "string"), and can be shown in the datastore viewer for individual entities because they've actually been deserialized. In Java and Python code, these are mapped by your application via the datastore API to Java and Python types. But there's no sense in which the data as stored in the datastore "is" a `java.util.Date`; it's stored as `gd.when` and can be read from the same datastore as a Python `datetime.date`.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, it confirms my doubts (so the kind must be fetched to know all its properties and corresponding java classes ! correct ?) ... but could you explain me the meaning of property_representation, i don't understand its goal !?

Comment: I don't think you can even infer the Java type 100% of the time from the entity itself; for example a gd:when could be a date, a datetime, or a time. Your application needs your class definitions to be able to translate. If I understand it correctly, the property_representation is just how the values are stored in the indexes; many datastore types map to the same representation because for the indexes you just need something sortable to search on; INT64 is sufficient if you don't care about what the data means, just how to find it.